# How to add New Folder icon in Eclipse tool bar?

Tags: shortcuts, eclipse

I see that there are icons for new class, new package etc in my eclipse tool bar. However can anyone point me where I can configure so that I also have an icon to create a new folder? I'm not looking for adding a new External Tool rather an icon beside New Class icon.

Comment: If it existed it would be in `Window > Customize Perspective` on the `Tool Bar Visibility` tab, but there does not seem to be a option for new folder there.

Comment: yes, I did verify there, but couldn't find it.